# Exporting an object as ".json" file, how? (Blender 2.8)

Tags: objects, export, file-format

I've searched since hours now on the internet and didn't found any solution for this problem. So, i want to export an object as an .json file for a game, that only uses that kind of file. I've seen, there are add-ons for older versions of Blender to be able to export objects as .json files. My problem is, that can't find an solution for the latest version of Blender (2.8).

Comment: JSON is not a 3D format in itself, it's a format to store key and value pairs. It says pretty much nothing about the expected file format that you need.

Comment: Maybe "three.js" says more about the file format i need?

Comment: Here you go this should help set you on the right track. https://github.com/supermedium/aframe-particleplayer-component/tree/master/exporters/blender2.8

Comment: A little late but for anyone looking, this worked for me:
https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/blender-minecraft-json-model-import-export.80517/